# Mat-select is not selecting option

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I have a form with a mat-select field. I initialize this field with the values coming from backend through an API call. But mat-select is not selecting any values from the options. I tried with all possible answers I have found in Stack Overflow from the previous questions about this issue, but none of those working.

my component's ts file :

```
levels = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 

ngOnInit() {
      this.myService.getData.subscribe((res) => {
         this.initForm(res);
      })
  } 

 initForm (data) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Level: [data ? data : ""]
 });
```

My component's html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
       <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p">
        <mat-label>Level</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="Level">
       <mat-option value="i" *ngFor="let Level of levels; index as i">{{ Level }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

In my levels array it can have only values 1, 2, 3, 4 and response will also contain a value from 1-4. And data is coming correctly I have checked using console log. Basically, in this form I have several fields all of those working correctly except this mat-select field. Other fields are not mat-select field.

Comment: Try to put the `value` of `mat-option` between "[]" here your value seems to always be i. by not using the [] you use the string 'i' and not the value of the variable `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can found in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-68009852) 2 workings exemple for your issue.

One of the issue in the code you share is the missing [] on the `mat-option` value the other I think is the use of the index that start at 0 putting an offset in the data you can have in your form

if it's still not that the issue is not in this part of code